# What do you call a person who has interest in every field?

Tags: single-word-requests

Some persons are interested in everything, they want to know everything, want to have knowledge in everything. they can't just sit calmly without having a question in their mind?
What do you call those persons?

Comment: polymath,  
noun, 
a person of wide-ranging knowledge or learning:

Answer (score 1):

Persons who not only want to know about everything but who, to a certain extent, do know about everything, are called *universalists*.

> ([Dictionary com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/universalist)) **universalist**
> [ yoo-nuh-vur-suh-list ]
> noun
> 1.a person characterized by universalism, as in knowledge, interests, or activities.

> ([Dictionary com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/universalism)) **universalism**
> [ yoo-nuh-vur-suh-liz-uhm ]
> noun
> 2. a universal range of knowledge, interests, or activities.

Such people can also be called *omniscients*.

> ([Dictionary com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/omniscient)) **omniscient** [ om-nish-uhnt ]
>
> 1. adj. -  having complete or unlimited knowledge, awareness, or understanding; perceiving all things.
> 2. noun -  an omniscient being.